# Can I send commands to a program I opened in a .bat file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to create a batch file that I can click on that launches all of the stuff I need for rails development:

1)A command prompt opened to the folder the code for the project is in

2)A command prompt opened to the folder the project is in
  -Then I want to have that window call "rails s"

3)Send the windows key + left-arrow to the first command prompt to move it to the left side of the screen

4)Do (3) with the second window, but with the right side of the screen

5)Open up a file explorer to the folder I am developing in

6)Open up sublime text to the folder that I am developing in

What I have so far is:

```
@echo off
start cmd /k cd C:\projects directory\code
start cmd /k cd C:\projects directory\code
subl C:\\"projects directory"\code
```

Is what I want to do possible?

Answer (score 0):

1 and 2 are all good. I'm going to go ahead and say 3 and 4 aren't. 
5 can be done with the code below:

```
C:\Windows\explorer.exe (Directory you want to open here)
```

And it would seem you have 6 worked out already.